# jQuery event on 3 click in one second

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I'm beginier in JavaScript and jQuery and I have one question.

How I can create event that will run function on third click, but all 3 clicks must happen in one second.
If first two clicks are in 00:01s but third click is in 00:02s, do nothing, all clicks must be in 00:01s (one second).

Best Regards.

Comment: You can do this with `setTimeout`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var clicks = 0;
$('.someclass').click(function(){
     clicks++;
if(clicks == 3){
     // do something;
   }
  if(clicks==1) setTimeout(function(){ clicks=0; },1000);
});
```

See the [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/3bo4nwhj/)